# My imageview not showing up after swiperefreshlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, swiperefreshlayout

For some reason, my imageview under swipe refresh layout doesn't show up.
The elements in the recyclerview would show up fine but anything under the recylerview would not.

```
<LinearLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       tools:context="com.example.disen.chefu.food_categories.second_category">

       <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:id="@+id/refresh_second_catg"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/second_category_rcV"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        <ImageView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/light"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
       <ProgressBar
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/second_progress"
         android:visibility="invisible"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
         android:indeterminateBehavior="repeat"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can u share expected output

Comment: can you share a screenshot of how it looks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical">
       <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
           android:id="@+id/second_category_rcV"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

       <ProgressBar
           android:id="@+id/second_progress"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
           android:indeterminateBehavior="repeat"
           android:visibility="visible" />

   </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

RESULT

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try giving SwipeRefreshLayout height of 0 and a weight of 1. I think that should work. One possible reason ImageView is not visible could be that the list being displayed in RecyclerView is large enough to cover up the entire screen and leaving no space for ImageView.